# Why Channel interface redefine close() method?

Tags: java, nio, jdk1.4

The close() method has already defined in the Closeable interface, why Channel redefines it again?

```java
package java.io;
import java.io.IOException;

public interface Closeable extends AutoCloseable {
    public void close() throws IOException;
}
```

```java
package java.nio.channels;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Closeable;

public interface Channel extends Closeable {

    public boolean isOpen();

    public void close() throws IOException;

}
```

Comment: Possibly just for clarity and readability, but you'd have to ask whomever at Oracle wrote that line.

Comment: Because `Channel` is from 1.4 and `Closeable` is from 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unfortunately not copied the most important parts - the JavaDoc.

The JavaDoc of `Channel#close()` clarifies quite a bit of the channel-specific details for this method, for example that subsequent operations throw `ClosedChannelException`, and how this method behaves when multiple threads are involved, especially blocking behavior.

<sub>Also, `Channel` predates `Closeable` (introduced in 1.4, `Closeable` in 1.5) and was retrofitted with that interface.</sub>